# Is there a source download for the Python pickle module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pickle

I accidentally edited the pickle module file and I can no longer import it. In addition, python does not run anymore. Is there a source to download the built in libraries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to pip install pickle in python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477949/not-able-to-pip-install-pickle-in-python-3-6)

Comment: No, unfortunately not, I can't use pip because pickle is messed up. I need the original pickle file from python 3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of alternatives:

1. grab a copy of the code from the [git repository](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/pickle.py) (assuming you meant you just changed the `.py` file)
2. reinstall Python from where-ever you installed it from, probably uninstalling it first

Comment: Ok I'll do that

Comment: note that you really shouldn't modify code from the standard library!  you also want to be very careful you get the right version if you're grabbing from git.  reinstalling is probably the better option