# How to pip install pickle under Python 3.9 in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, pickle

I need the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) package installed under my `Python 3.9` under Windows 10.

### What I tried

When trying with `pip install pickle` I was getting:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pickle
> (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pickle

Then I tried the solution suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477949/not-able-to-pip-install-pickle-in-python-3-6) using `pip install pickle5` but got the following error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

I then tried to install the Tool suggested by the error but got same error message after trying again `pip install pickle5`.

### Question

Which is the correct way to install [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) package under `Python 3.9` in Windows 10?

### UPDATE

There is no need to install `pickle` module as it comes already installed along with `Python 3.x`. Just needed to do `import pickle` and voila!

Comment: pickle is part of the standard library, so there is no need to pip install it.
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477949/not-able-to-pip-install-pickle-in-python-3-6/48477988

Comment: @DivideByZero I tried the solution stated in that question but failed. It's even under a different Python version. I would not say this is a duplicate. Even the solution I suggest is different and the error message I get when `pip install pickle5` is not mentioned in that question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Cedric UPDATED answer is right. Pickle exists within Python 3.9. You don't need pip install pickle. Just use it.

```
import pickle
```

Comment: Great answer! thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found a way that I'm not sure it's the optimal but it works.

I did `pip install pickle4`

And then in the script just

```
import pickle4 as pickle
```

### UPDATE

There is no need to install `pickle` as it's already within `Python 3.9`. Just needed to `import pickle` and voila!

Answer (score 1):

For Generalized Summary, for almost all Python versions, you never need to worry for installing 'pickle' as it comes already installed with the python interpreter.
Hence, simple import works:

```
import pickle
```

In case this doesn't work, refer to [Pickle Install Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477949/not-able-to-pip-install-pickle-in-python-3-6/48477988) on Stack Overflow.
Another suggested way is to run: `pip install pickle-mixin`

For other Queries and Info, refer to [Python Pickle Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Answer (score -1):

> pip install pickle5

is the best possible way for installing pickle.

Comment: The "best possible way"? Why not use [the built-in module](https://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)?